# Io.jsonwebtoken.security.SignatureException: JWT signature does not match locally computed signature

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-webflux, bearer-token, jwt

**Hi guys, I need help.**

I´m learning *Spring WebFlux* and *jwt authentication*, so I'm doing a REST service to practice, but this error won't let me continue, I don't know how to fix it.

**Error:**

```
io.jsonwebtoken.security.SignatureException: JWT signature does not match locally computed signature. JWT validity cannot be asserted and should not be trusted.
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:411) ~[jjwt-impl-0.11.1.jar:0.11.1]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.AuthorizationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.ExceptionTranslationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.logout.LogoutWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.savedrequest.ServerRequestCacheWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.SecurityContextServerWebExchangeWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.ReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.header.HttpHeaderWriterWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity$ServerWebExchangeReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.WebFilterChainProxy [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/api/v1/character/users" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Stack trace:
        at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:411) ~[jjwt-impl-0.11.1.jar:0.11.1]
        at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:541) ~[jjwt-impl-0.11.1.jar:0.11.1]
        at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parseClaimsJws(DefaultJwtParser.java:601) ~[jjwt-impl-0.11.1.jar:0.11.1]
        at com.rostenross.webflux.configuration.JWTUtil.getClaimsFromToken(JWTUtil.java:53) ~[classes/:na]
        at com.rostenross.webflux.configuration.JWTUtil.getUsernameFromToken(JWTUtil.java:58) ~[classes/:na]
        at com.rostenross.webflux.configuration.AuthenticationManager.authenticate(AuthenticationManager.java:32) ~[classes/:na]
        at com.rostenross.webflux.configuration.SecurityContextRepository.lambda$3(SecurityContextRepository.java:55) ~[classes/:na]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:125) ~[reactor-core-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1784) ~[reactor-core-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:151) ~[reactor-core-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:127) ~[reactor-core-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:118) ~[reactor-core-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2346) ~[reactor-core-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxFilterFuseable.java:191) ~[reactor-core-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:169) ~[reactor-core-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:110) ~[reactor-core-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:96) ~[reactor-core-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
        at
```

### Now, this is *my code*:

**JWTUtil: **

```
@Component
public class JWTUtil {
    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JWTUtil.class);

    private String secrete = "RostenRoss35689682_Nestor_Matias_Costantini_16/04/1991_programador-universitario_profesor-de-quimica";
    private String expireTimeInMilliSec="30000";

    public String generateToken(User user) {
        Date now =new Date();
        Map<String, Object> claim = new HashMap<>();
        claim.put("alg", "HS256");
        claim.put("typ", "JWT");
        
        return Jwts.builder()
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256,Base64.getEncoder().encode(secrete.getBytes()))
                .setClaims(claim)
                .setSubject(user.getUsername())
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 864000000))
                .claim("rol", user.getAuthorities().stream().collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .compact();
    }
    
    public Claims getClaimsFromToken(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(secrete.getBytes()))
                .parseClaimsJws(token.replace("Bearer ", ""))
                .getBody();
    }
    
    public String getUsernameFromToken(String token) {
        return getClaimsFromToken(token).getSubject();
    }
    
    public Date getExpirationDate(String token) {
        return getClaimsFromToken(token).getExpiration();
    }
    
    public Boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
        Date expirationDate = getExpirationDate(token);
        log.info("isTokenExpired: "+expirationDate.before(new Date()));
        return expirationDate.before(new Date());
    }
    
    public Boolean isTokenValidated(String token) {
        return !isTokenExpired(token);
    }
}
```

---

**SecurityContextRepository: **

```
    @Component
public class SecurityContextRepository implements ServerSecurityContextRepository {
    
    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityContextRepository.class);
    
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> save(ServerWebExchange exchange, SecurityContext context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Mono.empty();
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<SecurityContext> load(ServerWebExchange exchange  ) {
        String bearer = "Bearer ";
        return Mono.justOrEmpty(exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().getFirst(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION))
                .filter(b -> b.startsWith(bearer))
                .map(subs -> {
                    log.info("Substring: "+subs.substring(7));
                    return subs.substring(7);
                    }
                )
                .flatMap(token ->
                    Mono.just(
                            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(token,
                                                                    token
                                                                    ,Collections.singletonList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"))
                            )       
                    )
                )
                .flatMap(auth -> authenticationManager.authenticate(auth).map(SecurityContextImpl::new));
    }   
}
```

---

**AuthenticationManager: **

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationManager implements ReactiveAuthenticationManager{

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthenticationManager.class);
    
    @Autowired
    private JWTUtil jwtUtil;
    
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    
    @Override
    public Mono<Authentication> authenticate(Authentication authentication) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        log.info("autenticaion inicio");
        String token =authentication.getCredentials().toString();
        String userName= jwtUtil.getUsernameFromToken(token);
        return userRepository.findByUsername(userName)
                .flatMap(userDetails -> {
                
                    log.info("role: "+userDetails.getAuthorities().toString());
                    if(userName.equals(userDetails.getUsername()) && jwtUtil.isTokenValidated(token)) {
                        return Mono.just(authentication);
                    }else {
                        log.info("userDetails: "+userDetails.toString());
                        return   Mono.just(authentication);
                    }
                });
    }
    
    
}
```

---

**SecurityConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityConfig.class);
    
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repo;
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    @Autowired
    private SecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository;
    
    
    @Bean
    ReactiveUserDetailsService userDdetailService() {
        return (name) -> repo.findByUsername(name);
    }
    
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain (ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http.authorizeExchange(
                authorizedExchangeSpec -> authorizedExchangeSpec
                    .pathMatchers("/api/v1/character/singin","/api/v1/character/login", "/api/v1/character/about","/api/v1/character/all","/api/v1/character/id=**","/api/v1/character/name=**")
                        .permitAll()
                    .anyExchange().authenticated()

        )
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint((response, error) -> Mono.fromRunnable(()->{
                    response.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
                })).accessDeniedHandler((response,error) -> Mono.fromRunnable(()->{
                    response.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
                })).and()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .csrf().disable()
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .securityContextRepository(securityContextRepository)
                .requestCache().requestCache(NoOpServerRequestCache.getInstance())
                .and()
                .build();
    
                
    }
}
```

---

**pom.xml: **

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.rostenross.webflux</groupId>
    <artifactId>CharactersAPI</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>CharactersAPI</name>
    <description>TV and comics charactes reactive API.</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
                
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

---

If you need more information let me know.
I've looked everywhere on the web and found nothing.

> Thanks ind advance guys.

Comment: is there any particular reason to why you are not using the built in functionality of JWT declared in the spring security documentation, instead of implementing some custom `ReactiveCustomAuthenticationManager` https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-architecture and some custom `JWTUtil` class?

Comment: all you need to do is basically set up a custom NimbusJwtDecoder https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-decoder-builder `Nimbus` is already included in spring security so why pull in `JJWT`? https://bitbucket.org/connect2id/nimbus-jose-jwt/src/master/

Comment: `I've looked everywhere on the web and found nothing.` Start by looking in the official spring documentation for spring security.

Comment: The error itself shows a signature issue, so you may need to check your token signature secret key is the same as when doing the token generation. And if no special reason, you should use spring default lib and decoder like @Toerktumlare mentioned above